# Codeigniter My_Controller error with default object from empty value

Tags: codeigniter

What is my problem is I using php version 5.4 will have this error in MY_Controllar, kindly take a look the screenshot as below

[image]

but there are not problem below php version 5.3

here is my code

```
 <?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $data->the_leave_data = $this->leave_data(); <--- line 8 is here
        $this->the_leave_data = $data->the_leave_data;
        $this->load->vars($data);
    }

    function leave_data()
    {
        $data = array();
        $this->load->model('leave_data_model');
        $staff_id = $this->session->userdata('staff_id');
        if($query = $this->leave_data_model->get_by('staff_id',$staff_id))
        {
            $data['leave_data_records'] = $query;           
        }
        var_dump($data);
        return $data;
    }

}

?>
```

here is the var_dump return value from $data

```
leave_data_records' => 
object(stdClass)[21]
  public 'leave_data_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'staff_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'annual_leave' => string '1.0' (length=3)
  public 'sick_leave' => string '0.0' (length=3)
  public 'annual_leave_balance' => string '0.0' (length=3)
  public 'sick_leave_balance' => string '0.0' (length=3)
  public 'year' => string '2012' (length=4)
```

Any Idea how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: this is likely to be a deprecation bug in CodeIgniter, please report this to them directly

Comment: Any solution for this yet? From what I gather this seems to be only a problem with newer versions of php. Everything seems to work fine, still annoying to have this error pop up everywhere though. I guess I'll just turn down the error reporting for now ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you using PHP 5.4?
PHP 5.4 has strict standards. You need to declare $data as an object of stdClass:

```
$data = new stdClass();    
$data->the_leave_data = $this->leave_data();
```

Answer (score 0):

Means that `$this->leave_data();` is empty.

I don't see no where, to be loaded with data inside your controller. If you define it somewhere else end it's loaded from within `CI_Controller`... you should do `parent::$this->leave_data();`

Comment: Hi w0rldart, thanks for reply, I got var_dump the $data, it's got return value, but it's still got the error

Comment: so you're saying that `var_dump($data);` after de eight line, outputs values?

Comment: ya, I had update my post, kindly take a look the return value in var_dump

Comment: Have tied using `$data` as an array, instead of an object?